# Obtener el header del response con JAXB

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb

Hola espero se encuentren bien, he estado intentando obtener el header del response de un servicio SOAP, con el siguiente método me retorna el objeto pero con los valores null

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
   msgHdrRs1 = (ResponseHeader)       
   unmarshall.unmarshal(it.next().getSource());
   System.out.println(msgHdrRs1);
}
```

Pero veo que no están nulos porque cuando los itero obtengo los encabezados como en este ejemplo

```
while (headers.hasNext()) {
                                SOAPHeaderElement element = null;
                                element = headers.next();
                                if (element.getElementQName().equals(new QName(
                                        "namespace", "ResponseHeader"))) {
                                    System.out.println("Entró " + element.getElementQName().getNamespaceURI() + " "
                                            + element.getElementQName().getLocalPart() + " Value: "
                                            + element.getChildElements());

                                    // ob = JAXBUtils.unmarshall(context, element);
                                    // msgHdrRs = (ResponseHeader) element;
                                    Iterator childElements = element.getChildElements();
                                    while (childElements.hasNext()) {
                                        Object nextElement = childElements.next();
                                        if (nextElement instanceof SOAPElement) {
                                            SOAPElement elementC = (SOAPElement) nextElement;
                                            Iterator usernameTokenElements = elementC.getChildElements();
                                            Object next;
                                            while (usernameTokenElements.hasNext()) {
                                                if ((next = usernameTokenElements.next()) instanceof SOAPElement) {
                                                    SOAPElement nextEl = (SOAPElement) next;
                                                    if (nextEl.getLocalName().equals("code")) {
                                                        System.out.print(nextEl.getTextContent());
                                                    } else if (nextEl.getLocalName().equals("desc")) {
                                                        System.out.print(nextEl.getTextContent());
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("No Entró " + element.getElementQName().getNamespaceURI() + " "
                                            + element.getElementQName().getLocalPart());
                                }
                            }
```